# Foundation joyride start only on first load

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I'm using Foundation Joyride and every time I load the webpage the tour starts, but how do I only start the tour for the first time the webpage is loaded?

My settings are ...

```
$(window).load(function() {

    //Foundation Joyride (Tour)
    $("#tour").joyride({
        'cookieMonster': true,
        'cookieName': 'JoyRide',
        'cookieDomain': 'mydomain.co.uk/',
        'postRideCallback' : function () {
            $(this).joyride('destroy');
        },
        cookieMonster: false
    });

});
```

Comment: Oops just deleted my previous comment! Sorry. If you could take a look at www.grahamsimmons.com/cookie you can see my simple example :o)

Comment: I'm using Chrome and a plugin to see cookie information and I see no cookies being set at all!

Comment: You have to include the jQuery.cookie library (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) witout that joyride can't set cokies; try it

Comment: I did have it included, but still couldn't get it to work, so I took it back out. I've added it back in now.

Comment: Have changed it, but no luck still.

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes from the options (see my answer), and the cookieDomain option

Comment: That makes sense, but still not working.

Comment: I've removed them, but still not working. Bonkers this is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working at last and it turned out to be the order in which the header files were declared.

```
<html>
<head>              
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="foundation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.foundation.joyride.js"></script>      
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
    $("#tour").joyride({
        cookieMonster: true,
        cookieName: 'JoyRide'
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ol id="tour">
        <li><p>This is the tour.</p></li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `cookieMonster` option se to true, with your domain or false in `cookieDomain`.

Also remove the `cookieMonster: false` outside of the parenthesis.

To let joyride use cookies you must include the `jQuery.cookie` library in your page (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Here is a sample:

```
$("#tour").joyride({
    cookieMonster: true,
    cookieName: 'JoyRide',
    cookieDomain: false
});
```

In this way you'll see the tour only the first time you visit the page (or when you clear the cookies).

Comment: Couldn't get that to work. I have the web developer plugin for Chrome and I see no cookie being set at all. Is something stopping cookies do you think?

Comment: Your jQuery cookie seem to be corrupted! Can you fully include it again from the joyride package?